# Can a sequence converge but be not Cauchy? Any examples?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus, cauchy-sequences

I know that not every Cauchy sequence is convergent. How about the other way around? Can someone bring up an example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In for example the reals a sequence converges iff it is Cauchy.

Comment: No, but a sequence can be Cauchy and not convergente. (for exemple $x_n=\frac{1}{n}\in(]0,1[,\mathcal T_{[0,1]})$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

$$|x_n-x_m| = |x_n - L + L - x_m| \leq |x_n-L|+|x_m-L|.$$

The analogous thing works in metric spaces. This trick is very common in lots of situations in analysis, so it would do you well to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

But Note that in general **Converse** is not true i.e. A Cauchy sequence is not necessarily a convergent sequence. For example if our space is $X=\mathbb Q$, then 
$$
x_n=\frac{\lfloor n\sqrt{2}\rfloor}{n},
$$
is a Cauchy sequence which DOES NOT converge is $\mathbb Q$. It DOES converge is $\mathbb R$ but not in $\mathbb Q$.